# mysql duplicate results joining tables

Tags: mysql, join

I am rolling my own functionality for a well known cart. Here is my query:

```
    SELECT d.product, d.product_id, p.price FROM cscart_product_descriptions AS d, cscart_product_prices AS p WHERE d.product_id IN (
SELECT product_id FROM cscart_products WHERE product_code IN (
SELECT product_id FROM cscart_range WHERE range_name IN (
SELECT range_name FROM cscart_range WHERE product_id = '0140885'
)))
```

When I remove the product_prices related selection from the first select, I get three items returned as expected. When I run it with the prices included, I get something like 4,500 results.

I am aware that this is a joining issue, I'm just not certain how to correct it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its doing a cross join with cscart_product_prices table..

you could try something like this:

```
 select a.*,p.price from (
      SELECT d.product, d.product_id 
      FROM cscart_product_descriptions AS d 
      WHERE d.product_id IN (
         SELECT product_id FROM cscart_products WHERE product_code IN (
         SELECT product_id FROM cscart_range WHERE range_name IN (
         SELECT range_name FROM cscart_range WHERE product_id = '0140885'
         )))a
join cscart_product_prices AS p
on p.product_id=a.product_id
```

Comment: OK that worked for me after a little editing. What is the join keyword doing to prevent cross joining?

Comment: when you use , between two table names and without any where conditions, it will act as a cross join, results to Cartesian product..you could use the key word join with an ON condition to aviod the same

Comment: OK so cross joining is the default option and join over-rides that and allows you to respect table relations. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Also, try this query with joins -

```
SELECT
  d.product, d.product_id, p.price
FROM
  cscart_product_descriptions d
JOIN cscart_products p
  ON p.product_id = d.product_id 
JOIN cscart_range r1
  ON r1.product_id = p.product_code
JOIN cscart_range r2
  ON r2.range_name = p.range_name
WHERE r2.product_id = '0140885'
```